# Excel: Parametrizing using Microsoft Query

Tags: excel, parameter-passing, microsoft-query

I use Excel as front end to display data from a database. Concretely, I have customer information in a MariaDB database and with sql I extract for each customer
information from the database using Microsoft Query/ODBC:

```
SELECT name, n_consultation
FROM consultation
WHERE customer_id = 1
```

So, for each customer I have one Excel workbook with five sheets where each sheet has another sql-query with the same customer.

To create a new Excel workbook I make a copy of the Excel workbook of customer 1, change name of the workbook and in each sheet I change the `WHERE` part by changing
the `customer_id = 1` to `customer_id = 2`. This I can do quite fast by short cuts (ALT+V, J, etc.).

Having 10 customer and 5 sheets for each workbook I have to do 50 changes and this is feasible. But in case of 100 customer this is not manageable. Is there a
way to use a parameter with Microsoft Query/ODBC?
For example, the queries could be written with:

```
SELECT name, n_consultation
FROM consultation
WHERE customer_id = @id
```

and `@id` can be defined in the first sheet.

If this is not possible I suppose that the only alternative is using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to change the SQL syntax at Queries & Connection--> Properties --> Definition tab like follows
`WHERE customer_id = ?`.